# How can I have a map array?

Tags: c++

How do I load Levels in my game, as in Layer 1 would be Objects, Layer 2 would be Characters and so on. I only need 3 layers, and they will all be put on top of each other. i.e having a flower with a transparent background to be put on grass or dirt on the layer below.I would like to Read From the same file too. How would i go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

I load the map from a level file which are just numbers corresponding to a tile in the tilesheet.

And here is the code that interprets it

```
void LoadMap(const char *filename, std::vector< std::vector <int> > &map)
{
    std::ifstream openfile(filename); 
    if(openfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line, value;
        int space;

        while(!openfile.eof())
        {
            std::getline(openfile, line);

            if(line.find("[TileSet]") != std::string::npos)
            {
                state = TileSet;
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.find("[Layer1]") != std::string::npos)
            {
                state = Map;
                continue;
            }

            switch(state)
            {
            case TileSet:
                if(line.length() > 0)
                    tileSet = al_load_bitmap(line.c_str());
                break;
            case Map: 

                std::stringstream str(line);
                std::vector<int> tempVector;

                while(!str.eof())
                {
                    std::getline(str, value, ' ');
                    if(value.length() > 0)
                                 tempVector.push_back(atoi(value.c_str()));
                }
                map.push_back(tempVector);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
  }
  }
```

and this is how it draws the map. Also the tile sheet is 1280 by 1280 and the tilesizeX and tilesizeY is 64

```
void DrawMap(std::vector <std::vector <int> > map)
{    
    int mapRowCount = map.size();

    for(int i, j = 0; i < mapRowCount; i ++)
    {
        int mapColCount = map[i].size();

        for (int j = 0; j < mapColCount; ++j)
        {
              int tilesetIndex = map[i][j];
              int tilesetRow = floor(tilesetIndex / TILESET_COLCOUNT);
              int tilesetCol = tilesetIndex % TILESET_COLCOUNT;    
              al_draw_bitmap_region(tileSet, tilesetCol * TileSizeX, tilesetRow * TileSizeY, TileSizeX, TileSizeY, j * TileSizeX, i * TileSizeX, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDUqv.jpg

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. I thought you needed a hint on how to do it, but then you showed how you did it yourself. Are you asking to review the code? Or are you having any trouble with that code?

Comment: Just as a general point, you shouldn't be using vectors for this. Your map is a *definite* size, and so you can dynamically allocate an array of integers of that size. Vectors are singly-linked lists, so, when using operator[], if you access something before the internal iterator, it has to start from the beginning of the list again. Also, you're passing your vector by copy to your DrawMap function; this is going to be slow without compiler optimization. Pass it as a const reference, e.g., `void DrawMap(const int &map)` where `int *map = new int[rows * cols];`

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, they code above actually just puts the map underneath it not over it. Ill add a picture to maybe show it better.

Comment: Granted, you're accessing the vector elements sequentially, but it's still not the best tool for the job.

Comment: Correction: they are not implemented as singly-linked lists, but as dynamically allocated arrays. Still, though, there's additional overhead in the package to resize the array, whereas your map is staying the same size. It's overkill at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need more than one two-dimensional array.

Try something like this:

```
unsigned int map[3][8][8];
#define OBJECTS_LAYER 0
#define CHARACTER_LAYER 1
#define FLOWER_ID 2

//...

map[OBJECTS_LAYER][3][4] = FLOWER_ID;
```

### Edit 1

Per the OP's description, a layer is a 2 dimensional array, 8 x 8, which would be represented as:

```
unsigned int layer[8][8];
```

Th OP's map has multiple layers.  This translates into a container of layers.
One method is to use another dimension of the array.  Much like a layered cake, or floors in a building.

```
unsigned int map[/* maximum layers */][8 /* from layer above */][8 /* from layer above */];
```

To access the position [3,4] of layer 1 the expression would be:

```
map[0][3][4]
```

Since indices are zero-based in C++, the first layer has index of zero.

To access floor 3, row 2, column 7 of a building one would use the nomenclature:

```
empire_state_building[2][1][6]
```

Comment: Sorry, could you expand a bit.

Comment: @Manl400:  I guess you would put it in the place where you need your `map` and layers; or where you need to access it.  Have you ever stored values in a variable before?  Same thing.  How do you access your layers currently?

Comment: Would it be in one of the voids I stated above?